# jquery conditional button

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, if-statement

I have a button  that I need to apply a class to if a value retrieved from a database is blank.
I think there is something wrong with my syntax in the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var videoURL = '<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>';
    if ($videoURL == "") {
        $('#video').addClass('invisible');
    }
    else {
        $('#video').click(function(e) {
            $('#imageMain').html('<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="435" height="244" src="' + videoURL + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
            $('.featuredOverlay').hide();
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be if(videoURL == ""), you've added the dollar sign which is a jquery convention for "this is a jQuery encapsulated object" but no such variable exists.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed it but there still seem something wrong as the class doesn't get applied

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the URL? make sure it's genuinely empty and doesn't contain whitespace etc.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an existing class you need to use removeClass first or try toggleClass.

Comment: and you're not inheriting from something then?

Answer (score 0):

You declared variable as 'videoURL'

```
var videoURL
```

and then you try to compare with $ before 'videoURL'

```
if ($videoURL == "")
```

Comment: Try to switch the line '<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>' to  "<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>" . Do you see any javascript errors in your browser. You may also want to add: alert(videoURL); after it is assigned to see what is its value

Comment: do you see any javascript errors in your browser? did you try to alert the videoURL ?

Answer (score 0):

videoURL is not a jQuery element so, change $videoURL to videoURL.

Try forcing php content or use console.log to debug your data

```
var videoURL = "a string";
console.log(videoURL);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/qmemmkp4/1/